# Color Matrix of all Image Effects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, image-processing

Can you tell me the color matrix of all the image filters effects like:

1. GaussianBlur
2. Sharpen
3. Smooth
4. EdgeDetectQuick
5. EdgeDetectConvolution
6. EdgeEnhance
7. OutLine
8. Sepia
9. Solarize
10. Sobel

I can change my images easily by using pointers in C#, but that is unsafe, so I'm avoiding it. The other way to change the pixel data is color matrix. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Oded : I am trying to change Bitmap Images by applying filters like ACD SEE software does... I can achieve that by the use of Pointers but that harmful.. so i am looking for is colormartix for each effets

Comment: Wrong tool, ColorMatrix can only work on one pixel at a time.  Almost all of the effects you listed requires sampling multiple input pixels for each output pixel.  Use a graphics library.

Comment: @Hans Passant : Can you pin point which graphic library you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a unique matrix for each image processing.
They usually depend from some parameter (like σ for [**Gaussian Blur Matrix**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)) and should be generated before using them to processing image.

For some matrix examples and explanation look at this [**Link**](https://web.archive.org/web/20080414234642/http://student.kuleuven.be:80/~m0216922/CG/filtering.html)

Anyway, there are some description also on Wikipedia:

- [**Gaussian Blur Matrix**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)
- [**Sobel Operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use color matrix. You can change each pixel, but it will take too much time for high quality pictures.

I hope this link is useful. It was for me!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2.aspx

This one is a little bit more complicated:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx